# iOS build fails in Xamarin Activation step after upgrading to Xcode 8.0 on the agent

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-devops

I have a mac setup as a Xamarin build agent for Visual Studio and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). On Friday, Xcode updated itself to 8.0 with the iOS 10 SDK. This, of course broke everything. I managed to get Visual Studio to reconnect after upgrading both Xamarin iOS on the mac and Xamarin for Visual Studio.

Now, my only issue that is that the [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-osx) agent fails to build. This agent runs on the same machine as the Visual Studio agent that works (e.g. I can build in Visual Studio and it builds on the mac and gives me an ipa). I haven't changed any build settings since the upgrade.

Here is where it fails, in the Xamarin Activation build step:

[image]

Yes, I double and triple checked that the XamarinPassword variable is correct. In fact, if I enter the wrong password, it will fail with an invalid login error.

Here is the error:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Activate Xamarin license
******************************************************************************
warning MT0061: No Xcode.app specified (using --sdkroot), using the system Xcode as reported by 'xcode-select --print-path': /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
error MT0052: No command specified.
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch --datafile
Xamarin.iOS 10.0.0 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator0.0.sdk
Failed to activate Xamarin license. {"code":1,"message":"An internal error occurred. Please email us at contact@xamarin.com and make sure to include the address associated with your Xamarin account ."}
Return code: 1
```

Is the VSTS agent ready for iOS 10? Should I downgrade everything back to before Friday and before the Xcode 8.0 update? Am I missing something new in the configuration?

Comment: Based on this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin), You no longer need a Xamarin license to build your Xamarin app. We're deprecating the Utility: Xamarin license task. What’s the result if you remove that task and build?

Comment: @starain yup, that fixed it! Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: How do you 'remove the task'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that you can remove Xamarin license task, because it is no longer needed to build Xamarin app. (refer to this [article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin))